# SOAP Web Service method naming conventions

Tags: web-services, soap, naming-conventions, naming

Consider a Web Service (e.g. SOAP-based) that has an operation which accepts a bulk of data from the client. From the server's point of view it is receiving data, but from the client's point of view it's sending data. How should that operation be named? The options are

- ImportData
- ExportData / SendData

Is there a *de facto* standard for naming these things? How do web services usually name these?

Thank you for your opinions.

Answer (score 7):

It's a *service*. It's there to *serve*. Name operations from the client's point of view.

Answer (score 5):

Here are the W3C specifications for Simple Object Access Protocol (SOAP) v1.2 specifications: https://www.w3.org/TR/soap12/.

Section 3.1.1 says that a URI should be used to name a feature and should "[enable] the feature to be unambiguously referenced...".

Further, section 5 of [this document](https://www.ehealthontario.on.ca/architecture/education/courses/service-oriented-architecture/downloads/SOA-ServiceNamingConventions.pdf) says:

"All capability names SHOULD follow 'verb' + 'noun' + ['subject'] format, where:

- 'verb' is the action that the consumer is performing; and
- 'noun' is the name of the primary object on which the action is being performed."

Hope this helps someone (9 years later).